# Edit: Python - Going from 1 Player to Two Player Game Using Functions

Tags: python, function

I posted something similar earlier, but I did a horrible job of asking the right question. 
I'm trying to code a two player connect four game, but can only manage a 1 player game, with the user playing against the computer. Can anyone help me with trying to write a 2 player approach to the game? I'm still quite a beginner and am still learning the ropes, so apologies if this is still not a good question and/or is too vague.

Here's my current code:

```
import random

def winner(board):

# Check rows
    for row in range(6):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] == board[row][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # Check columns 
    for col in range(6):
        for row in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] == board[row + 2][col] == board[row + 3][col]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # Check diagonal A

    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(4):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col + 1] == board[row + 2][col + 2] == board[row + 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]


    # Check diagonal B

    for row in range(5, 2, -1):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] == board[row - 2][col + 2] == board[row - 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

    # Tie (just returns an empty string)
    return ""

def printBoard(board):
# there are probably better ways to print a board, but I didn"t want to bother with another function, especially since the number of columns and rows are fixed in this game.

    print ("   1   2   3   4    5   6   7")
    print ("1: " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " | " + board[0][4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6] + " | " + board[0][7])
    print ("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---")
    print ("2: " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board [1][6] + " | " + board [1][7])  
    print ("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print ("3: " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board [2][4] + " | " + board [2][5] + " | " + board [2][6] + " | " + board [2][7])
    print ("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print ("4: " + board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board [3][4] + " | " + board [3][5] + " | " + board [3][6] + " | " + board [3][7])
    print ("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print ("5: " + board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board [4][4] + " | " + board [4][5] + " | " + board [4][6] + " | " + board [4][7])
    print ("  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+")
    print ("6: " + board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board [5][4] + " | " + board [5][5] + " | " + board [5][6] + " | " + board [5][7])
    print

def playerMove(board):

        validMove = False
        while not validMove:
            col = input("What column would you like to play? :")
            for row in range (6,0,-1):
                if (1 <= int(row) <= 6) and (1 <= int(col) <= 7) and (board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] == " "):
                    board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] = "X"
                    validMove = True
                    break
            else:
                print ("Invalid input. Please try again!\n")

def computerTurn(board):

    validMove = False
    while not validMove:
        row = random.randint(0,5)
        col = random.randint(0,6)
        for row in range (5,0,-1):
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "O"
                validMove = True
                break


def game():
    openCells = 42
    playerTurn = True
    count = 1
    newBoard = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]


    while not winner(newBoard) and (openCells > 0):
        printBoard(newBoard)
        if playerTurn:
            playerMove(newBoard)
            playerTurn = not playerTurn
        else:
            computerTurn(newBoard)
            playerTurn = not playerTurn
        openCells -= 1

    printBoard(newBoard)
    if (winner(newBoard) == "X"):
        print ("You Won!")


        print ("\nGAME OVER")
    elif (winner(newBoard) == "O"):
        print ("The Computer Won!")
        print ("\nGAME OVER")
    else:
        print ("Tie!")
        print ("\nGAME OVER \n")
```

**EDIT:I modified my code so that I got rid of the computerTurn function and incorporated 2 user inputs in my playerMove function, however my game keeps looping back to player name inputs instead of alternating between turns.
Here's the new code (note that only the last couple functions were changed):**

```
def playerMove(board):
    turn = 0
    players = []
    numPlayers = 2
    checkers = ['X','O']
    for i in range(numPlayers):
        players.append(input("Please enter player"+str(i+1)+" name: "))

    validMove = False
    while not validMove:
        col = input(players[turn]+" what column would you like to play? :")
        for row in range (6,0,-1):
            if (1 <= int(row) <= 6) and (1 <= int(col) <= 7) and (board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] == " "):
                board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] = "X"
                validMove = True
                break
            else:
                print ("Invalid input. Please try again!\n")

def game():
    openCells = 42
    playerTurn = True
    turn = 0
    players = []
    numPlayers = 2
    count = 1
    newBoard = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]


    while not winner(newBoard) and (openCells > 0):
        printBoard(newBoard)
        playerMove(newBoard)
        playerTurn = not playerTurn  
        openCells -= 1

    printBoard(newBoard)
    if (winner(newBoard) == "X"):
        print ("You Won!")


        print ("GAME OVER")
    elif (winner(newBoard) == "O"):
        print ("The Computer Won!")
        print ("GAME OVER")
    else:
        print ("Tie!")
        print ("GAME OVER")


game()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far for achieving 2-player functionality? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: So instead of defining a computerTurn function, I tried to incorporate 2 user inputs in the userMove function. This allows the input and works, but I can't get the game execution function (def game()) to coordinate with the userMove function on its own.

Comment: Try the OOP way, make 2 objects for 2 users with parameters and move the player name thing in the __init__ and a static function for calculating stuff between the details of 2 players to determine winner.

Comment: Didn't think of using OOP, but I'll try it to see if I can manage to code it that way. Sounds a lot more intuitive and cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, and that way you can optimise the calculating function for n users as well without writing any extra code for new users, try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler way: I made a new function, `playerMoveO`, and renamed your old one `playerMoveX`. I made playerMoveO look like this:

```
def playerMoveO(board):

    validMove = False
    while not validMove:
        col = input("You are the O player. What column would you like to play? :")
        for row in range (6,0,-1):
            if (1 <= int(row) <= 6) and (1 <= int(col) <= 7) and (board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] == " "):
                board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] = "O"
                validMove = True
                break
        else:
            print ("Invalid input. Please try again!\n")
```

I also changed playerMoveX to look like this:

```
def playerMoveX(board):

    validMove = False
    while not validMove:
        col = input("You are the X player. What column would you like to play? :")
        for row in range (6,0,-1):
            if (1 <= int(row) <= 6) and (1 <= int(col) <= 7) and (board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] == " "):
                board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] = "X"
                validMove = True
                break
        else:
            print ("Invalid input. Please try again!\n")
```

Then, I changed the main loop, but I replaced the `computerTurn` function with `playerMoveO`. It works fine :D

**EDIT**
Obviously, there is a cleaner way. In this one, the `playerMove` function is passed the current symbol. So:

```
def playerMove(board, symbol):

    validMove = False
    while not validMove:
        col = input("You are the {} player. What column would you like to play? :".format(symbol))
        for row in range (6,0,-1):
            if (1 <= int(row) <= 6) and (1 <= int(col) <= 7) and (board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] == " "):
                board[int(row)-1][int(col)-1] = symbol
                validMove = True
                break
        else:
            print ("Invalid input. Please try again!\n")
```

And in the main loop, there is a variable, `currentSymbol`, which is changed after each turn:

```
def game():
openCells = 42
playerTurn = True
count = 1
newBoard = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]
currentSymbol = "X"

while not winner(newBoard) and (openCells > 0):
    printBoard(newBoard)
    playerMove(newBoard, currentSymbol)
    if currentSymbol == "X": currentSymbol = "O"
    elif currentSymbol == "O": currentSymbol = "X"
    openCells -= 1

printBoard(newBoard)
if (winner(newBoard) == "X"):
    print ("X Won!")


    print ("\nGAME OVER")
elif (winner(newBoard) == "O"):
    print ("O Won!")
    print ("\nGAME OVER")
else:
    print ("Tie!")
    print ("\nGAME OVER \n")
```

Comment: It works! I can't believe I didn't think of just treating the computer function as a user one and then editing it accordingly. Thanks for the wonderful solution!

Comment: Yeah! @greatdonut, I've just edited my answer, there is a better way to do this.